# Vuetify Calender with 0 minute event Overlap eachother

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have some events which is supposed to have same start and end (meaning 0 minute event). You can say it is not an event but a reminder of some sort.

```js
const events = [
    {
        start: '2021-06-20T01:00:00',
        end: '2021-06-20T01:00:00',
        timed: true
        // and other relevant properties
    }
]
```

Regardless, When I define some events with 0 minute event, they don't stack. One just overlaps another completely.

[image]

However, if I add 1 minute to end time, they stack on each other as they are supposed to.
[image]

I tried doing same on Google Calendar with two 0 minute events at same time, and it is rendered properly.
[image]

I looked everywhere but cannot find the answer (Or I thought I looked everywhere). Also, I cannot seem to get the 12h format on Japanese locale.

#### CodePen

Here is the CodePen that shows in more detail of what my problem is:
https://codepen.io/bhujelaayushgc/pen/ExWJXQd

Comment: Please share more code for better insight of your issue.

Comment: @LiroDasmaz Apologies for not doing it from the beginning. I have added CodePen that shows the issue along with more code.